# What's a 'simply put' difference between Sx and S(x)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The professor wouldn't really put it bluntly enough.

This is a rookie question but I don't know what to search for (suggestions appreciated).

What's the difference between:

$C_n = \{X \in C:|X| = n\}$

vs

$C(n) = \{X \in C:|X| = n\}$

Do they vary in terms of usage in other formulas or is it really just a syntactic sugar?

Comment: I haven't seen either notation before, but it seems like they both are alternate notations for the same concept.

Comment: Both definitions, of $\;C_n\;$ and of $\;C(n)\;$ are exactly the same, thus they both are different notations for the same thing...and none is a general, well-known and accepted notation.

Comment: @DonThousand My first guess would be (being a programmer) is that $Cn$ defines n as a parameter that has to be mentioned upon "call", ergo: $C_{n=3}$ whereas $C(n)$ only requires proper order: $C(3)$

How far off am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your professor has a set $C$ whose elements are themselves sets and is interested in discussing the subsets of $C$ containing those elements whose cardinality is $n$, one for each value of $n$. So those subsets get a name that depends on $n$. That name could be $C(n)$ or $C_n$. It will be used in the discussion that follows, but has no standard meaning. Either notation is fine.

Comment: Okay, is this model valid then:

$S(g)$ = [sum of values in g]
$U = \{X \in C:S(X) = 5\}$

Can I pass $X$ as $g$ parameter this way and will I in result get all $X$ inside $C$ whose sum equals 5?

edit: should I post a separate question then, seeing that you guys have helped me out grasp the main question?

Comment: There's not enough context to make sense of this extension. You haven't said anything about being able to _sum_ things in subsets $X$ of $C$. And what you can pass as a parameter may be programming language dependent. You'd better ask another question. If possible, provide a complete toy example showing us what is actually in $C$.

Comment: “Either notation is fine”—weak disagreement here. If $C$ is a set, then it is not\* a function. The notation “$C(n)$” strongly suggests that $C$ is a function, whereas $C_n$ has no such implication; the former notation is misleading. (\* For the purposes of this question, I do not identify a function with its graph; that is a set-theoretic implementation detail.)

Comment: @wchargin not quite all functions are relations, all relations are subsets of a Cartesian product, and a Cartesian product is a set of tuples with each tuple ordered by the ordering of the sets in the product.  so a function is a set, we just use separate notation.

Comment: @wchargin I concur with your weak disagreement. $C_n$ is better.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: See my parenthetical. That’s true in some set-theoretical formalisms, but conceptually it needn’t be. And in that case $C(n)$ would be even _more_ confusing; as a function, it should refer to $\text{unique}(\{ y : (n, y) \in C \})$, but now we’re redefining it to also mean $\{ X \in C : \lvert X \rvert = n \}$? Clearly not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think your teacher, is just wanting to set a standard. $C_n$ is notation, sometimes used for a sequence element, or a subset with certain properties.  $C(n)$ is typically a function notation. A function has exactly 1 output, for every input, mathematically speaking. If C was a function, the latter could work. The former, might need more explanation. In either case, consistent use when writing it down in a paper etc, will greatly help stiffle any confusion.